# Get value from multiple input and search Array match (With AND e OR)

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, input

In the function onclilck, I have to get the value from each input and search with that value, a match in my array and then report in DIV "result". The problem is that I have to do it with a logical AND search, so using ALL the values ​​together if present. I can not do it, can someone help me? I have to use only javascript or jQuery- NO PHP. Thank you.`

```
 $("#search").click(function(){ 

    var pharmacies = [];

    pharmacies[0] = ["Vaccaro", "Bagheria", "90011"];
    pharmacies[1] = ["Greco", "Bagheria", "90011"];
    pharmacies[2] = ["Timoneri", "Bagheria", "90011"];

    var names = [];
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("campi");
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; ++i) {
        if (elem[i].value !== "") {
            names.push(elem[i].value);
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input class="campi" id="nome" type="text" name="name">
<input class="campi" id="indirizzo" type="text" name="address">
<input class="campi" id="città" type="text" name="city">
<input class="campi" id="cap" type="text" name="zip">

<button id="search" type="submit">Cerca</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: the value obtained from the inputs must be used for the AND search in the array.

Comment: So whats the issue? Loop through the pharmacies array and check if the input value has a match in pharmacies array using [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or perhaps [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). Then if it does, then show it to result div, by setting its innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

1. Copy the `pharmacies` array to a `temp array`.
2. Get all `<input>` element.
3. Search among `<input>` elements for given value.
4. Delete array element, if given value not found.
5. Remove undefined values from Temp array.
6. Print the temp array.

**Result:**

```js
var pharmacies = [
    [ 'Vaccaro', '', 'Bagheria', '90011' ],
    [ 'Greco', '', 'Bagheria', '90011' ],
    [ 'Timoneri', '', 'Bagheria', '90011' ]
];

function search() {
    var tempArr = pharmacies.slice( 0 ),
        elem = document.getElementsByClassName( 'campi' );

    for ( let i = 0; i < elem.length; ++i ) {
        var value = elem[ i ].value

        if ( value ) {
            for ( var j = 0; j < tempArr.length; ++j ) {
                if ( tempArr[ j ] != undefined ) {
                    if ( tempArr[ j ].indexOf( value ) == -1 ) delete tempArr[ j ]
                }
            }
        }
    }

    tempArr = tempArr.filter( Boolean );
    printResult( tempArr )
}

function printResult( arr ) {
    if ( arr.length ) {
        var result = '<table><tr><th>#</th><th>Nome</th><th>Indirizzo</th><th>Città</th><th>Cap</th></tr>';

        for ( var x in arr ) {
            result += '<tr><td>' + (+x + 1) + '</td>'
            for ( var y in arr[ x ] ) {
                result += '<td>' + arr[ x ][ y ] + '</td>'
            }
            result += '</tr>'
        }

        result += '</table>'
    } else {
        result = 'No data found'
    }

    document.getElementById( 'result' ).innerHTML =  result
}
```

```css
input {
    margin: 5px
}
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ddd
}
```

```html
<input class="campi" id="nome" type="text" name="name" placeholder="nome">
<input class="campi" id="indirizzo" type="text" name="address" placeholder="indirizzo">
<input class="campi" id="città" type="text" name="city" value="Bagheria" placeholder="città">
<input class="campi" id="cap" type="text" name="zip" placeholder="cap"><br>
<button id="search" type="submit" onclick="search()">Cerca</button><br><br>

<div id="result"></div>
```